# preg_match: can't find substring which has trailing special characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a function which uses preg_match to check for if a substring is in another string.
Today I realize that if substring has trailing special characters like special regular expression characters (. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -) or @, my preg_match can't find the substring even though it is there.

This works, returns "A match was found."

```
$find = "website scripting";
$string =  "PHP is the website scripting language of choice.";

if (preg_match("/\b" . $find . "\b/i", $string)) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

But this doesn't, returns "A match was not found."

```
$find = "website scripting @";
$string =  "PHP is the website scripting @ language of choice.";

if (preg_match("/\b" . $find . "\b/i", $string)) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

I have tried preg_quote, but it doesn't help.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Edit: Word boundary is required, that's why I use \b. I don't want to find "phone" in "smartphone".

Comment: `preg_quote` should work, can you echo out `preg_quote($find)`

Comment: `preg_quote` won't work since you have `\b` at the end. Remove it if you do not need to check for a trailing word boundary.

Comment: It's not at all clear what behavior you want with search string like `)@#*$ek2` or `abc%` or `abcdef ` (note a space at the end).

Comment: @stribizhev Yes I need word boundary, that's why I used \b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just check if the characters around the search word are not word characters with look-arounds:

```
$find = "website scripting @";
$string =  "PHP is the website scripting @ language of choice.";

if (preg_match("/(?<!\\w)" . preg_quote($find, '/') . "(?!\\w)/i", $string)) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/DkSl4F)

Result: `A match was found.`

Note the double slash used with `\w` in `(?<!\\w)` and `(?!\\w)`, as you have to escape regex special characters in interpolated strings.

The `preg_quote` function is necessary as the search word - from what I see - can have special characters, and some of them must be escaped if intended to be matched as literal characters.

**UPDATE**

There is a way to build a regex with smartly placed word boundaries around the keyword, but the performance will be worse compared with the approach above. Here is sample code:

```
$string =  "PHP is the website scripting @ language of choice.";

$find = "website scripting @";
$find = preg_quote($find);
if (preg_match('/\w$/u', $find)) {   //  Setting trailing word boundary
    $find .= '\\b'; 
} 
if (preg_match('/^\w/u', $find)) {   //  Setting leading word boundary
    $find = '\\b' . $find;
}

if (preg_match("/" . $find . "/ui", $string)) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

See [another IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/rRbNXm)

Comment: The problem stays the same if the goal is to match "scripting @" in these cases `"scripting @ "` or `"scripting @,"` and not in these cases `"scripting @@"` or  `"scripting @a"`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Just close the question as unclear. With a single example. The OP is asking us to guess around these edge cases.

Comment: @Jonny5: Thank you, I missed that part, now updated. Casimir, as for whether this solves the problem in full or not, in most cases it is enough to just check for word characters before and after a keyword.

Comment: Actually, it is not a big deal to create a function that adds correct boundaries. @HungTran, please let me know if you are interested.

Comment: Thank you @stribizhev for your great and fast answer! Your answer already solves my problem.. But if it is possible please help me create that function. I believe it will help the community alot.

Comment: @HungTran: Here you are. I still believe that the first approach should work for you, and there is nothing unclear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to find a string from another string, you can `strpos()`.

Ex.

```
<?php

$find = "website scripting";
$string =  "PHP is the website scripting language of choice.";

if (strpos($string,$find) !== false) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, `stripos` could be helpful, as the search is case-insensitive, but what about the whole word requirement (i.e. no more letters or numbers or underscore around the keyword)?